# Missing tree data with virtual scroll with flex height for angular-tree-component

Tags: angular, tree, angular-tree-component

I am trying to use flex height for the tree with virtual scroll. However, when I set the tree container to `100%` and set the flex height, the chunk of data is missing from the screen during the scroll.

I have added the working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2mavw

If I open the last rootDynamic49 node, only 20 children are visible. However, it has 50 children. On the other hand, when I set the height to `100px`, all the children are visible.

Is there a way where I can keep the first div fixed on the top position and add scroll only for the tree with the flexible height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `height: 100%;` and expand the tree, the virtual scroll's viewport height is not getting updated to the new height of the tree. It stays at it's `px` value. We can omit this css altogether and set the `height` in the `container` instead, using `display: grid;`

**app.component.css**

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto calc(100vh - 38.4px); // StackBlitz adds 8px padding to body and 'First div' has a height of 22.4px (8 + 8 + 22.4 = 38.4px).
}
```

`calc(100vh - 38.4px)` needs to be replaced by your desired height. Using `%` values here seems counterintuitive to what you mentioned in the OP about the 'First div' being fixed in the top position because if the `div` is given `100%` it will stretch as per its content and whole `div` would scroll out of view.

Then all you need to is use `display: inline;` on the `tree-container` so that it fits within the main `div`.

**angular-tree.component.css**

```css
.tree-container {
    display: inline;
}
```

**Note**: I have used `22.4` for the `nodeHeight` since on inspecting the nodes, the height is exactly `22.4px`.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-component-virtual-scroll). Here's a [preview](https://angular-tree-component-virtual-scroll.stackblitz.io) of the same.